# Dynamical Systems. Bendixson's and Dulac-Bendixson's theorems.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems, online-resources

I am looking for a place to read the proofs of the Bendixson and Dulac-Bendixson theorems.
Namely, let $D$ be a simply connected set and the following system be defined in $D$, and
\begin{align}
\dot x &=P(x,y), \\
\dot y &=Q(x,y),
\end{align}
then the following theorems hold.

**Theorem: (Bendixson)** Given that $P_x+Q_y$ doesn’t change sign in $D$, the system does not have a non-constant periodical solution.

**Theorem: (Dulac-Bendixson)** If a function $B(x,y)\in C^1(D)$ exists, such that $(BP)_x+(BQ)_y$ doesn't change sign in $D$. Then the system does not have a non-constant periodical solution.

Comment: Notice that constants are periodic, and the theorems are NOT true then.  Both should say "does not have a non-constant periodic solution"!  Notice the proof, it wants a periodic orbit with an interior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read the proof right here, in short form:

Assuming a periodic orbit $C$ with interior $U$, $$\oint_C(BQ\,dx-BP\,dy)=\oint_C B(\dot y\,dx-\dot x\,dy)=0$$ because $\dot y\,dx-\dot x\,dy=0$ along the orbit. Now use Green's theorem to conclude $$\iint_U\bigl((BP)_x+(BQ)_y\bigr)\,dx\,dy=0.$$You now have your contradiction. This proves Dulac–Bendixson; Bendixson follows by setting $B=1$.

Comment: Great timing, I was just typing essentially the same thing. While this is clear from what you wrote, I want to emphasise that $U$ has positive area because $C$ is embedded. ($C$ is embedded by uniqueness of solutions to ODE.)

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. You may have long forgotten this question but I still have some issues unresolved. How did you use that $P_x+Q_y$ doesn't change sing in D? Is that why $\dot y\,dx-\dot x\,dy=0$ along the orbit? Why does $\dot y\,dx-\dot x\,dy=0$ along the orbit?

Comment: The sign question: If you integrate a positive function over $U$, you get a positive result, not zero. Similarly if the function is negative. For the other question, along an orbit you have $dx=\dot x\,dt$ and $dy=\dot y\,dt$.